# Finding the middle item in an array from a given list

Tags: java, arrays

Given a sorted list of integers, output the middle integer. A negative number indicates the end of the input (the negative number is not a part of the sorted list). Assume the number of integers is always odd.

Ex: If the input is:

> 2 3 4 8 11 -1

the output is:

> Middle item: 4

The maximum number of list values for any test case should not exceed 9. If exceeded, output "Too many numbers".

Hint: First read the data into an array. Then, based on the array's size, find the middle item.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class LabProgram {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      int[] userValues = new int[9];  // Set of data specified by the user      
      int middleItem;
      /* Type your code here. */
      for(int i=0; i<userValues.length; ++i){ 
         while(userValues[i]>=0){
         userValues[i] = scnr.nextInt();
         }
      } 
      
      if(userValues.length>8){
            System.out.println("Too many numbers");   
      }
      else{
            middleItem = userValues[userValues.length/2];
            System.out.println("Middle item: " + middleItem);
      }   
   }
}
```

The main issue so far is finding a way to scan in fewer than the maximum allowed number of array items and having the loop stop when a negative number is entered. I've deleted the code to use negative integers as a sentinel value to focus on scanning and accepting fewer inputs. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Change your `while()` to a `do {} while()`. That way you first check the input, then decide if you want to loop once more.

Comment: userValues[Math.round(userValues.length / 2 )], you don't need a loop.

Comment: @BerkKurkcuoglu how would I capture the user inputs for the array without a loop?

Comment: What's the expected output?  If the input is: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 -1, what's the output?

Answer (score 2):

You can read integers one by one and add them into a `List`, terminating when a negative number is entered, with a for loop.

```java
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
for (int x; (x = scnr.nextInt()) >= 0;)
    numbers.add(x);
System.out.println(numbers.get(numbers.size() / 2));
```

Comment: Thank you. This has actually pretty much almost solved the problem. My only issue now is figuring out the control flow for when someone puts in more than 9 entries. Currently it outputs both the "Too many numbers" and middle item outputs.

Comment: Just needed to use an if else loop and nest the 2 output messages after `number.add(x);`. Thanks again @Unmitigated